# Creating audio file after doing FFT and getting Amp,Freq,Phase infos

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, ifft

I'm using below codes to fo FFT first and then take the first 10 bigger amplitudes of FFT and corresponding frequency and phase informations.

At the end of te code, i'm trying to rebuild the original signal as much as possible but not using ifft because of the implementation that i'm trying.

Finally, i'm trying to write the .wav but getting "too many output arguments." error always.
Could you pls let me know about your feedbacks?

```
close all
clear all
clc

[audio,Fs]=audioread('C:\Users\xaol\Desktop\sound.wma');
audioinfo('C:\Users\xaol\Desktop\sound.wma')
player=audioplayer(audio,44100); play(player)

length_audio=length(audio);
%plot(audio);

audio1=audio(2^16:2^17);   %taking a part of audio
audio_part=2^17-2^16;      %the lenght of taken part
plot(audio1);
title('original partly signal');
player=audioplayer(audio1,44100); play(player)

%% FFT

NFFT = audio_part;
Y = fft(audio1,NFFT)/length(audio1);
fs=length(audio1)/length(audio1);  
f = fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

[B,IX] = sort(abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1))); %order the amplitudes
Amplitudes=B; %find all amplitudes 
Frequencies=f(IX(1+end-numel(Amplitudes):end)); %frequency of the peaks
Phases=angle(abs(Y));

%% 10 bigger amplitudes and corresponding frequency and phase are being found

A=B((length(IX)-9):(length(IX)));
F=Frequencies((length(IX)-9):(length(IX)));
P=angle(Y(IX((length(IX)-9):length(IX))))*180/pi;

FAP=[F;A;P]

%FAP is 3x10 matrix which includes frequency, amplitude and phase info

%% REBUILD ORIGINAL SIGNAL

ii=length(FAP);
org_audio=0;
t=0:length(audio1);

for i=1:1:ii
   org_audio=4*FAP(2,i)*exp(j*2*pi*FAP(1,i)*t+j*(pi/180)*FAP(3,i))+org_audio; 
end

figure, plot(t,org_audio)

audio_r1=abs(org_audio);
audio_r(:,1)=(audio_r1)';
audio_r(:,2)=audio_r(:,1);


filename='C:\Users\xaol\Desktop\sound2.wav';
AU=audiowrite(filename,audio_r,44100);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as the error suggests you have "too many output arguments". By looking at your code I believe that the problem is that `audiowrite` does not return any output arguments (have a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiowrite.html). You should use

```
audiowrite(filename,audio_r,44100);
```

instead.
In any case, you should learn how to use the MATLAB debugger (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) in order to identify where your error is.

BTW, the line `Phases = angle(abs(Y))` makes on sense as the absolute values do not have phase. Did you mean `Phases = angle(Y)`?

Comment: you are right, i was also using P for Phase and it overwrites Phase information correctly and forgot to erase while pasting my code. Actually i have tried so many options to write the data but no success till now. I have 2 columns of audio_r data as can be seen in code but can not record it.

Comment: @BRNCBKC: Also remember that `audio_r` should be normalised to `[-1 1]`